# rails before_action on csv download

Tags: csv, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm using devise to authenticate users. I want them to be able to look at the page without being logged in, but if they wish to download the csv data, they must be logged in. Here's how i've set up the csv download part

```
 respond_to do |format|
  format.html{
    render :layout => 'indices_show'
  }
  format.csv{
      export_to_csv(idxp)


      }
end
```

and here is the export_to_csv function

```
 def export_to_csv(idxf)
    cash = params[:cash]
    @title = get_title(@index)
    if (cash =='1')
      navs = @index.navsc.from(idxf)
      r = @index.returnsc.from(idxf)
    else
      navs = @index.navs.from(idxf)
      r = @index.returns.from(idxf)
    end
    dates = @index.dates.from(idxf)
    csv_string = CSV.generate do |csv|
      csv << [@title]
      csv << ["Date", "Return", "NAV"]
      dates.each_with_index do |d, i|
        csv << [d,r[i],navs[i]]
      end
    end

    send_data csv_string,
    :type => 'text/csv; charset=iso-8859-1; header=present',
    :disposition => "attachment; filename ="+ @title +".csv"

  end
```

At the top of this controller, I have,

```
 before_action :authenticate_user!, only:[:export_to_csv]
```

but it doesn't do anything as the user is still able to download the data without being logged in. I've found a semi work around by doing this,

```
 respond_to do |format|
      format.html{
        render :layout => 'indices_show'
      }
      format.csv{
        if (user_signed_in?)
          export_to_csv(idxp)
        else
          redirect_to new_user_session_path
        end
      }
    end
```

The problem here is that once the user logs in, it redirects to the homepage. Is there a way such that when a user clicks the download button, they are forced to sign in, and upon signing in they are redirected back to that page and the data is downloaded? Thanks

Comment: is `authenticate_user!` misspelled in your code like above?

Comment: no sorry, that was just a typo, i'll fix now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `before_action` isn't working because `export_to_csv` is not the method being called as the action - that would normally be the method your routing maps to - i.e. probably the method with your `respond_to` code in it.  Of course, you can split the method into two separate ones and have one for html and one for csv and then have the `before_action` set up for the csv one.  That's perhaps not so nice, especially if it's just two different viewing formats for the same data.  If they're not very similar views, perhaps it would be appropriate to separate them.  It depends on your app.

Another option is to use your second approach but modify it.  Before the `redirect_to new_user_session_path`, try inserting a call to `store_location_for(:user, request.request_uri)`, or perhaps pass `request.original_url`.  See here for the doc/code:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/store_location.rb#L26

You can see that if the stored location is present, it's used in preference to the root path:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb#L143

Note that `store_location_for` seems to be a recent addition to devise.  I'm actually using 3.1.x and it doesn't seem to be defined - you'd have to set the `user_return_to` session variable directly because that's what is checked during signin in 3.1.x.

Answer (score 1):

As Tim said, `export_to_csv` is not the method being filtered by `before_action`. It is firing actions based on the controller action methods at the top, and since you are trying to limit access lower down, it has already let the user through.

I'm not sure what the action name is that you are using, so I am going to assume it's `show`.

You can supply a conditional to your `before_action` line that may limit what you were hoping for.

```
before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:show], if: proc { request.csv? }
```